# fetching objects from core data not in a set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to fetch objects from core data that are not in a given set, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

For instance, suppose that we have a core data entity named User, which has a few attributes such as userName, familyName, givenName, and active. Given an array of strings representing a set of usernames, we can easily fetch all the users corresponding to that list of usernames:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSArray *userNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user1", @"user2", @"user3", nil];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName IN %@", userNames];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *users = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

However, I want to fetch the complement of that set, i.e., I want all the users in core data that don't have the usernames specified in the userNames array. Does anyone have an idea how to approach this issue? I thought it would be simple enough to add a `"NOT"` in the predicate `(i.e., "userName NOT IN %@")`, but Xcode throws an exception saying the predicate format could not be parsed. I also tried using the predicate builder available for fetch requests with no luck. The documentation wasn't particularly helpful either.  Suggestions? Comments? Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In order to find the objects that aren't in your array, all you have to do is something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (userName IN %@)", userNames];
```

That should return a request of all the objects without the ones you specified

Comment: Simple enough... Thanks, slev.

Comment: fantastic. I thought it was not working. but That was because the data in my array was from another field. Thanks. Simple and effective.

Comment: Note: This does not work with NSNumber variables which probably makes sense but is a shame if you wrap an enum in a NSNumber. In that case use something like `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (enumWrapper IN {%d, %d})", enum1, enum2]`.

Comment: not working for me.. :(  Although, `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName IN %@", userNames]` works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I am not strong at core data/objective-c but the predicate should be like the following statement;

```
[predicateFormat appendFormat:@"not (some_field_name in {'A','B','B','C'})"];
```

An example:

```
NSMutableString * mutableStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

//prepare filter statement
for (SomeEntity * e in self.someArray) {
    [mutableStr appendFormat:@"'%@',", e.key];
}

//excluded objects exist
if (![mutableStr isEqual:@""])
{
    //remove last comma from mutable string
    mutableStr = [[mutableStr substringToIndex:mutableStr.length-1] copy];

    [predicateFormat appendFormat:@"not (key in {%@})", mutableStr];
}

//...
//use this predicate in NSFetchRequest
//fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat];
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another useful example, showing how to take a list of strings, and filter out any which DON'T start with the letters A-Z:

```
NSArray* listOfCompanies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123 Hello", @"-30'c in Norway", @"ABC Ltd", @"British Rail", @"Daily Mail" @"Zylophones Inc.", nil];

NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF MATCHES[c] '^[A-Za-z].*')"];

NSArray *filteredList = [listOfCompanies filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];

for (NSString* oneCompany in filteredList)
    NSLog(@"%@", oneCompany);
```

I use this kind of `NSPredicate` when I'm populating a `UITableView` with an A-Z index, and want an "everything else" section for items which don't start with a letter.